# NAO (Choregraphe) Name error occuring whenever i run my code

Tags: testing, nao-robot, choregraphe

I have downloaded the `choregraphe 2.8.5` for `Nao`. I got same error whenever i try to run my code.

I have reinstalled the software but the problem has not resolved. 
This is the error I got.

> [ERROR] behavior.box :FMBox::createPythonModule:0 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_13970523248:/Say_2: Generated behavior class evaluation:  name 'ALBehavior' is not defined Behavior generated for this box does not seem to work. Please contact Aldebaran Robotics for further investigation.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: contact Aldebaran Robotics support https://account.aldebaran.com/support/

Comment: You might want to provide your code, is it standard boxes from the library, or custom python boxes ?